# Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: hibernate, spring, postgresql, transactions

I'm working on a application which uses spring and hibernate. We are using postgresql as the database.

When I try to insert a record into a table which has a OID column it is throwing the following error.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.greytip.cougar.model.misc.MailAttachment]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:135)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:48)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:882)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:692)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:319)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy5.sendMail(Unknown Source)
at com.greytip.cougar.module.ext.controller.TestMailController.testmail(TestMailController.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:259)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.IPAddressFilter.doFilter(IPAddressFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:229)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:286)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.SchemaDetectFilter.doFilter(SchemaDetectFilter.java:147)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:77)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.EmployeeSearchFilter.doFilter(EmployeeSearchFilter.java:77)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:228)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setBlob(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2817)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setBlob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1997)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2243)
    ... 75 more
```

The exception says that a Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode, but when i saw the following log from spring and hibernate it says that the auto-commit mode is disabled.

Here is the log from spring transaction and hibernate jdbc connection manager

```
Log:
2009-07-14 12:17:31,546 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - begin
2009-07-14 12:17:31,546 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - opening JDBC connection
2009-07-14 12:17:31,546 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - current autocommit status: true
2009-07-14 12:17:31,546 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - disabling autocommit
2009-07-14 12:17:31,546 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  - Getting transaction for [com.greytip.cougar.service.MailManager.sendMail]
2009-07-14 12:17:31,578 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - opening JDBC connection
2009-07-14 12:17:31,593 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  - Completing transaction for [com.greytip.cougar.service.MailManager.sendMail]
2009-07-14 12:17:31,593 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - registering flush begin
2009-07-14 12:17:31,609 [http-8080-5] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P01
2009-07-14 12:17:31,609 [http-8080-5] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
2009-07-14 12:17:31,609 [http-8080-5] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.greytip.cougar.model.misc.MailAttachment]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:135)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:882)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:692)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:319)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy5.sendMail(Unknown Source)
    at com.greytip.cougar.module.ext.controller.TestMailController.testmail(TestMailController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:259)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.IPAddressFilter.doFilter(IPAddressFilter.java:110)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:229)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:286)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.SchemaDetectFilter.doFilter(SchemaDetectFilter.java:147)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:77)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.greytip.cougar.system.security.EmployeeSearchFilter.doFilter(EmployeeSearchFilter.java:77)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
        at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:241)
        at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:228)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setBlob(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2817)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setBlob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1997)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2243)
        ... 75 more
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - registering flush end
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rollback
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - re-enabling autocommit
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rolled back JDBC Connection
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - performing cleanup
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2009-07-14 12:17:31,640 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
2009-07-14 12:17:31,656 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - performing cleanup
2009-07-14 12:17:31,656 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2009-07-14 12:17:31,656 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

In this log the first few lines says that the method MailManager.sendMail() is running with a transaction block and the default auto-commit status is true, but the next line says that the auto-commit is disabled.

Can anybody tell me why postgresql is throwing "Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode" exception when actually the auto-commit mode is diabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was there was two different SessionFactories in my application. Only 1 of them had an associated transaction. I was saving the object with the large object using a sessionFactory that didn't had the transaction.

Since the I was using dbcp pooling the connection had the autoCommit property set to true.

I fixed it by changing the use of two different sessionFactories, now I'm using only one sessionFactory which work in a HibernateTransaction. This solves the problem since the transaction manager sets the autoCommit property to false.

Answer (score 0):

for me adding @type(type= "...") annotation to field worked. you should define lob type i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. I used TransactionManagementType.BEAN and it didn't work. I changed it to TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER and it worked.