# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, transactional, lob

I am using Spring , JPA, Hibernate, Postgresql. I can upload/insert a file to the database. But I got the error when tried to access the file.

```
EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:172)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2BlobClob.<init>(AbstractJdbc2BlobClob.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Blob.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Blob.java:19)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Blob.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Blob.<init>(Jdbc4Blob.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet.getBlob(Jdbc4ResultSet.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBlob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBlob(DelegatingResultSet.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.get(ByteArrayBlobType.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractLobType.nullSafeGet(AbstractLobType.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1853)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:382)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:258)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:189)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:287)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.purchaseOrder.editForm_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f4(editForm_jsp.java:1884)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.purchaseOrder.editForm_jsp._jspService(editForm_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:650)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.templates.main_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(main_jsp.java:619)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.templates.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:178)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springbyexample.web.servlet.view.tiles2.DynamicTilesViewProcessor.renderMergedOutputModel(DynamicTilesViewProcessor.java:106)
    at org.springbyexample.web.servlet.view.tiles2.DynamicTilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(DynamicTilesView.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I remove the piece code from the JSP file, it is fine.

```
  <c:forEach items="${purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderQuotes}" var="document">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ${document.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${document.description}
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                ${document.filename}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${document.created}
                            </td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

the method that I retrieve the purchaseOrder:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public PurchaseOrder findById(Integer id)
    {
        log.debug((new StringBuilder("getting PurchaseOrder instance with id: ")).append(id).toString());
        try
        {
            PurchaseOrder instance = entityManager.find(PurchaseOrder.class, id);
            //            if(instance.getProjectFundingYears() != null)
            //                log.debug("get successful");
            //            log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
        }
        catch(RuntimeException re)
        {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

Here is the relationship of two Entities:

```
PurchaseOrder

@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase_order", schema =  "pta")
public class PurchaseOrder implements java.io.Serializable {

    ............

    private List<PurchaseOrderQuotes> purchaseOrderQuotes = ShrinkableLazyList
    .decorate(new ArrayList(), FactoryUtils
            .instantiateFactory(PurchaseOrderQuotes.class));

  .............................................................

    public PurchaseOrder() {
    }

....................................................................    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="purchaseOrder")
    public List<PurchaseOrderQuotes> getPurchaseOrderQuotes() {
        return purchaseOrderQuotes;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrderQuotes(List<PurchaseOrderQuotes> purchaseOrderQuotes) {
        this.purchaseOrderQuotes = purchaseOrderQuotes;
    }

............................................................................
}
```

PurchaseOrderQuotes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase_order_quotes", schema =  "pta")
public class PurchaseOrderQuotes implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String filename;
    private byte[] content;
    private String contentType;
    private Date created;
    private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;
    public PurchaseOrderQuotes() {
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "purchase_order_quotes_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="filename")
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    @Lob
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveByteArrayBlobType")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="content")
    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    @Column(name="content_type")
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="created")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_order_id", referencedColumnName = "purchase_order_id")
    public PurchaseOrder getPurchaseOrder() {
        return purchaseOrder;
    }
    public void setPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) {
        this.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;
    }
```

---

I am not clear . Sorry.
Here I dont access the BLOB file directly, I get its parent object.

I was able to upload the file and retrieve one purchaseOrder without any problem.
It only reports error when I add this piece code in the JSP file. But it should not try to access the BLOB field since I set FetchType.LAZY. I get confused.

```
<c:forEach items="${purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderQuotes}" var="document">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ${document.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${document.description}
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                ${document.filename}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${document.created}
                            </td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use large objects? What kind of binary data are you storing? Unless you want to store more than 1GB or need to access only parts of the BLOB, `bytea` is a much better choice.

Comment: I only need to allow people to upload a file with size <10M. I will try bytea to see what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have defined your Spring transactions via `@Transactional`, you are by default running inside of an auto-commit transaction.  As per [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123889/large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit-mode), you need to create a second session factory which runs in `autocommit = false` to retrieve the file.

Additionally, the DAO for the retrieval should be annotated with `@Qualifier` so that it knows which session factory to use.  Example:

```
@Autowired
public MyDAOImpl(@Qualifier("someSessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
   setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```