# Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode with Jpa+Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using Spring with Hibernate+JPA and a postgresql database. 
I have an entity with a Blob.

```
@Column
@Lob
private Blob serialized_object;
```

I have a repository I use to query for the entity but when I call any function it throws the following error even though I'm using the @Transactional annotation. Note: I have also used @EnableTransactionManagement in my configuration class.

Repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SerializedCustomClassifierRepository extends JpaRepository<SerializedCustomClassifier, Long> {

    SerializedCustomClassifier findById(long id);

    List<SerializedCustomClassifier> findAll();

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2556)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:172)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2BlobClob.<init>(AbstractJdbc2BlobClob.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Blob.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Blob.java:19)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Blob.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Blob.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Blob.<init>(Jdbc4Blob.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet.getBlob(Jdbc4ResultSet.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBlob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    ... 113 more
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585449/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit)

Comment: Don't use large objects unless you know what you are dealing with. The corresponding data type for the standard `BLOB` type is `bytea` in Postgres

Comment: I removed @Lob annotation and used only Blob but the error still persists.

Comment: On checking the database it seems that Blob is by default mapped to oid, the same when @Lob is used.

Comment: Ah my bad. I used byte[] and it resolved into bytea. Thanks!